# Why $y(0)=0$ implies $y=0$ for $y'=y$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Twenty years ago, my teacher of ODE said that the solution of $y'(x)=y(x)$ is ehm, trivailly, $y(x)=0$ or $y(x)=ke^x$. Since then, I have tried *everything* (MVT, tweaking with $e$ number...), but I couldn't prove that a solution that holds $y(0)=0$ is necessarily $y\equiv 0$.
A good link would succify. Thanks.

Comment: Let $z(t) = e^{-t} y(t)$ then note that $z'(t) = 0$ and so $z(t) = z(0)$. The latter follows from the MVT.

Comment: Seriously you defferentate and integrate for a single point??

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What single point and what integration?

Comment: Why is $z'(t)=0$?

Comment: Are you familiar with differentiating a product?

Comment: I am a Mathematician

Comment: Then differentiate $z$ as defined above.

Comment: Since $y’=y$ that quantity is $0$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/660453/72031

Comment: The general solution to $y'=y$ is $y=ke^x$ where $k$ is any constant (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58097/prove-that-c-ex-is-the-only-set-of-functions-for-which-fx-fx)). There's no need to treat the case $k=0$ separately and say “$y=0$ or $y=ke^x$”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answer says why 0 is a solution. To see why it's the only solution: the [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) roughly says that if $f(x, y)$ is continuous in $x$ and Lipschitz in $y$, then there's a unique solution for some closed interval around your initial condition. In the case of your ODE the relevant function is $f(x, y) = y$, which fulfills these requirements, so the solution is unique.

Comment: This is massive overkill.

Comment: I don´t think so. TVM and Bolzano, even Liouville, doesn't work. The problem is that the set of solutions if usually given as a fact. They ussualy  take $y=y'$ and then write $y'/y=1$, with no reagrds about if $y$ can have zeroes.

Comment: This is overkill.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku TBH I'm not a big diff eq person so I just pulled up the first existence and uniqueness theorem I could remember.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku: It might be overkill in this particular case, but it's still a useful general fact worth knowing that if the hypotheses for Picard–Lindelöf are satisfied, and if $f(y^*)=0$, then the equilibrium solution $y(x)=y^*$ is the unique solution to the initial value problem $y'=f(y)$, $y(0)=y^*$.

Comment: @ajotatxe: If you solve it using $e^{-x}$ as an integrating factor instead of using the method of separation of variables, there's no need to worry about $y$ being zero.

Answer (score 6):

If $y$ is differentiable and satisfies $y'=y$ then let $z(t) = e^{-t} y(t)$. Differentiating gives $z'(t) = e^{-t} (y'(t)-y(t)) = 0$. Hence $z'(t) = 0$ and so, by the mean value theorem, $z(t) = z(0)$.

Since $y(t) =e^t z(t)$, we see that $y(t) = e^t y(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

You can solve it and study the obtained solution.

In the present case, the solution to the proposed ODE is given by $y(x) = ke^{x}$.

Now it remains the question: when we assume that $y(0) = 0$, what does it imply?