# Does $e^{a+b}=e^{a}e^{b}$ implies that $ab=ba$ for banach algebras?

Tags: exponential-function, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra we khow that

> If $ab=ba$ then  $e^{a+b}=e^{a}e^{b}$

my question is

> Does $e^{a+b}=e^{a}e^{b}$ implies that   $ab=ba$?

Any comment or response is appreciated.

Comment: @Ennar. You're right. I thought I had found a different duplicate target. I'm certain I've seen this question here before.

Comment: Do you mean $ab=ba$ for a particular $a$ and $b$ or for all $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Writing out $e^{a+b}-e^ae^b$, I highly doubt that the vanishing of all those terms implies the vanishing of $ab-ba$. But I might be wrong.

Comment: Have a look at Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula.

Comment: @N. Ciccoli, only one direction is obvious from the formula, right?

Comment: Yes. On the other direction BCH tells you that if $e^ae^b=e^{a+b}$ then $\mathrm{Id}-\mathrm{ad}_a/\mathrm{ad}_a(b)=b$  so your question can be reformulated as: is it possible that $\mathrm{ad}_a(b)\ne 0$ but still $\mathrm{Id}-\mathrm{ad}_a/\mathrm{ad}_a(b)=b$, so it refers to injectivity of the map $z\mapsto \sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}z^{n-1}/n!$. If I remember correctly this function is at least locally injective around $0$, but at moment I cannot find a ref. Hope this rewriting helps.

Comment: @MPW, I mean for all $a, b$

Comment: See this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349180/if-ea-and-eb-commute-do-a-and-b-commute/349382#349382

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $e^A$ and $e^B$ commute, do $A$ and $B$ commute?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349180/if-ea-and-eb-commute-do-a-and-b-commute)  That question has a counterexample in $2 \times 2$ matrices.

Comment: Voting to reopen because the other question is clearly a different question. They might be equivalent but IMHO that requires a proof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a counterexample. Let the Banach algebra be the space of operators on a finite-dimensional Hilbert space. We can pick two orthonormal vectors, $|i\rangle$ and $|j\rangle$, and choose operators $\hat A$ and $\hat B$ as follows:
$$\hat A = 2\pi i |i\rangle \langle i| \, , \quad \hat B = 2\pi i |i\rangle \langle i| + |i\rangle \langle j | \, .$$

Then we see that
$$
\hat A^k = (2\pi i)^{k-1} \hat A \, , \quad 
\hat B^k = (2\pi i)^{k-1} \hat B \, , \quad 
(\hat A+\hat B)^k = (4\pi i)^{k-1} (\hat A+\hat B) \, .
$$

Therefore $e^{\hat A} = e^{\hat B} = e^{\hat A + \hat B}$ = I, which means $ e^{\hat A + \hat B} = e^{\hat A}e^{\hat B}$. Yet
$$
\hat A \hat B = (2\pi i)^2|i\rangle \langle i| + (2\pi i) |i\rangle \langle j|
\not =  (2\pi i)^2|i\rangle \langle i| = \hat B \hat A \, .
$$

Comment: Do you think using $i$ both for $\sqrt{-1}$ and for the index of your vector $|i\rangle$ is good notation?

Comment: @GEdgar It seems perfectly readable to me.

Comment: I'm just saying.  Why not call the orthonormal vectors $| 1 \rangle$ and $| 2\rangle$.  Or, as mathematicians do, $u_1$ and $u_2$.  Also, non-physicists may not know what $|i\rangle \langle i |$ means.