# Are there finite dimensional matrices for which $e^{A+B}=e^Ae^B$ when $A$ and $B$ do not commute?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-exponential

If we have square matrices $A$ and $B$ that commute (i.e. $AB=BA$), then we have $e^{A+B} = e^Ae^B$. In general this isn't true without the condition that $A$ and $B$ commute. I would like to know if this is "if and only if", or whether $A$ commuting with $B$ is just a necessary condition.

In other words, do there exist square matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $AB\ne BA$ but $e^{A+B} = e^A e^B$?

---

Not that it really matters because this question already got a very good answer, but I don't think this should be considered a duplicate of [Does $e^{a+b}=e^{a}e^{b}$ implies that $ab=ba$ for banach algebras?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3137242/does-eab-eaeb-implies-that-ab-ba), because that question is about Banach algebras whereas mine is only about ordinary finite-dimensional matrices.

Neither is it a duplicate of [If $e^A$ and $e^B$ commute, do $A$ and $B$ commute for finite dimensional matrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349180/if-ea-and-eb-commute-do-a-and-b-commute) (of which [Does $e^{a+b}=e^{a}e^{b}$ implies that $ab=ba$ for banach algebras?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3137242/does-eab-eaeb-implies-that-ab-ba) itself is closed as a duplicate), because that is clearly just a different question.

Comment: I believe the linked questions and answers do actually answer your question, *however* I voted to reopen this because It requires knowledge to see the connection which is beyond the level required to understand this question.

Comment: *“...this is not a duplicate of [Does $e^{a+b}=e^{a}e^{b}$ implies that $ab=ba$ for banach algebras?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3137242/does-eab-eaeb-implies-that-ab-ba), because that question is about Banach algebras and the only answer there is infinite-dimensional.”* This is not true. The answerer explicitly stated that *“Let the Banach algebra be the space of operators on a **finite-dimensional** Hilbert space”. In fact, his example is comprised of two $2\times2$ matrices $A=\pmatrix{2\pi i&0\\ 0&0}$ and $B=\pmatrix{2\pi i&1\\ 0&0}$.

Comment: @user1551 you are correct - I had just realised my mistake and will correct it. Still, I agree with Graviton's comment: someone looking for a simple result about matrices is likely to be mystified by that answer. (If that results in this being closed again I don't really mind, but I do think the answer here is valuable.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is possible to represent quaternions by $2\times2$ complex matrices or $4\times4$ real matrices ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations)).

For $A=2\pi(3\mathbf{i})$ and $B=2\pi(4\mathbf{j})$ we have $e^A=e^B=e^{A+B}=1$ because $(3,4,5)$ is a Pythagorean triple, even though $A$ and $B$ do not commute (indeed, they *anticommute*: $BA=-AB$).

This gives the explicit counterexample
$$
A = 2\pi\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
-3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -3 \\
0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix},\qquad
B = 2\pi\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
-4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -4 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$