# Prove that if $AB = BA$ then $\log{(AB)} = \log{(A)} + \log{(B)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponentiation, quantum-mechanics

#### Background

I am solving an assignment on the fundamentals of Quantum Computing which mostly has questions on Linear Algebra. All matrices and vectors are over **complex domains**.

#### Question

Define the exponent of a matrix as $$e^{\lambda A} = \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^i}{i!}A^i$$ where $A^0 = \mathbb{I}$ or the identity operator.

1. Given a matrix $B$, the matrix logarithm of $B$ is defined as the matrix $A$ such that $e^A = B$. Prove that $\log$ is a non-unique function (i.e. for every $B$, there are several $A$ that satisfy the matrix formula given).
2. Prove that for two matrices, if $AB = BA$, then $\log(AB) = \log(A) + \log(B)$.

#### My approach

1. For this part, I am firstly not sure about the existence of an $A$, it doesn't seem obvious to me why such an $A$ should always exist and if so, how to compute it. Nonetheless, assuming that we have *a* solution to $\log(B) = A$, then I try to prove that I can derive a family of solutions from it (this is my intuition)
   $$\therefore B = \mathbb{I} + A + \frac{A^2}{2!} + \frac{A^3}{3!} + \ldots $$
   Assume we have an $A' = A + 2\pi i \mathbb{I}$ such that
   $$ e^{A'} = \mathbb{I} + (A+2\pi i)\mathbb{I} + \frac{({A + 2\pi i\mathbb{I}})^2}{2!} + \frac{({A + 2\pi i\mathbb{I}})^3}{3!} + \ldots $$
   Since $A$ and $\mathbb{I}$ always commute, we can write the sum as (the proof is just algebraic manipulation and application of the binomial theorem, so I've skipped it)
   $$e^{A'} = \left(\mathbb{I} + A + \frac{A^2}{2!} + \frac{A^3}{3!} + \ldots\right)\left(\mathbb{I} + \frac{2\pi i}{1!}\mathbb{I} + \frac{(2\pi i)^2}{2!}\mathbb{I} + \frac{(2 \pi i)^3}{3!} \mathbb{I} + \ldots \right)$$
   $$\therefore e^{A'} = e^A \mathbb{I} \left(1 + \frac{2\pi i}{1!}+ \frac{(2\pi i)^2}{2!}\ + \frac{(2 \pi i)^3}{3!} + \ldots \right)$$
   $$\therefore e^{A'} = e^A \mathbb{I} e^{2 \pi i} = B$$
   Similarly $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, \exp{(A + 2n \pi i \mathbb{I})} = B$
   This finishes the proof
2. Assume $e^X = AB, e^Y = A, e^Z = B$
   To prove that $X = Y + Z$
   We write out the expansions of $A$ and $B$ and then use the fact that $AB = BA$
   $$AB = \mathbb{I} + (Y + Z) + \frac{Y^2 + 2YZ + Z^2}{2!} + \frac{Y^3 + 3Y^2Z + 3YZ^2 + Z^3}{3!} + \ldots$$
   $$BA = \mathbb{I} + (Y + Z) + \frac{Y^2 + 2ZY + Z^2}{2!} + \frac{Y^3 + 3ZY^2 + 3Z^2Y + Z^3}{3!} + \ldots$$
   Put $AB - BA = \mathbb{O}$
   $$\therefore (YZ - ZY) + \frac{1}{2!} (Y^2Z - ZY^2) + \frac{1}{2!}(YZ^2 - Z^2Y) + \ldots = 0$$

**This is where I am stuck**
Obviously if $Y$ and $Z$ commute, then the above expression equates to 0 and thus from the expansions of $AB$ and $BA$, if $Y$ and $Z$ would commute, $AB = BA = e^{Y+Z} = e^X$ and thus our proof is complete.

The question is: how do I prove that **this is the only case where the summation is 0? If $Y$ and $Z$ don't commute, then is it possible to proceed with the proof? Are there any alternate approaches?**

Comment: Do you have conditions on the matrix $A=e^X$? The matrix logarithm doesn’t exist if $A$ is singular.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is all the information that's given in the problem statement. I am not aware of this property for singular matrices, so that could be an interesting side question!

Comment: If $[A,B]=[e^Y,e^Z]=0$ then it is not necessarily the case that $[Y,Z]=0$, cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349180/if-ea-and-eb-commute-do-a-and-b-commute-for-finite-dimensional-matric

Comment: This doesn’t sound right if you pick a fixed (say, principal) branch of complex logarithm. E.g. $\log\big((-1)(-1)\big)=\log1=0\ne2i\pi=\log(-1)+\log(-1)$.

Comment: $e^X$ is always nonsingular so it make sense to restrict yourself to the non-singular case for $A=e^X$.

Answer (score 2):

As a comment to your question alludes to, you can only take the logarithm of invertible matrices
because $e^{A}$ is necessarily invertible: $e^{A}e^{-A}=I$.

---

As for the second part of your question, as you've said, it's just about showing that $e^C e^D=e^{C+D}$ whenever $C$ and $D$ commute.

By the way, the expanded power-series sum on each side is absolutely convergent, which means that it doesn't matter in which order you add up the terms of the sum. That's the **formal justification** for then rearranging the terms until they fit the same proof in basic analysis which shows that $e^{x+y}=e^x e^y$ for all complex numbers $x$ and $y$.